# UITableView with different optional sections?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am looking for a "good" way to solve some special requirements:

I have an UITableView with different sections, for example:

- Base Data
- About me
- Interests
- Images

Base Data contains always values (but there is still an variable row count) - and all other "Categories" could contain rows, or still could be empty. If there is no data, the category should be not shown.

No my first idea to solve that is:

Create all possible categories (but that could be 20 or more) - and do something like that:

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        var count:Int = 0

        switch (section) {
        case 0:
            count = baseHeaders.count
        case 1:
            if(mapItem.courses?.count > 0) {
                count = mapItem.courses!.count
            }
            break;
        default:
            count = 0
        }

        return count
    }
```

And ill check also with: *titleForHeaderInSection* if the count is null, and return then no header for the section.

BUT: is that a good way? My concern is about creating 20 sections and just 2 are used. Is there another, better way? Can i create sections manually? If yes, should i? So that only the base category is visible, and append everything else if there is data available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like my way of approaching such problems. I'm using enums (Obj-C & especially Swift) to handle and identify my Sections and I always return the full amount of potential sections:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return FormSection.count // enum function
}
```

In `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int`, however, I switch the unused sections off by returning 0 rows.

The benefit I saw after struggling with your type of dynamic tables was that all sections are always at the same index which made cell management relatively easy:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let section:FormSection = FormSection(rawValue:indexPath.section)!

    switch section {
    case .Header:
        //…
    default:
        //…
    }
}
```

The same goes for section headers/footers:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    switch section {
    case FormSection.Header.rawValue:
        return nil
    case FormSection.RoomSetup.rawValue where foo == false:
        return nil
    default:
        // return header with title = FormSection(rawValue: section)?.headerTitle()
        // Swift enums ftw ;)
    }
```

And the number of rows is calculated/fetched at runtime:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let section:FormSection = FormSection(rawValue:section)!
    switch section {
    case .Section1:
        return fooExpanded ? (numberOfFoo) : 0
    case .Section2:
        return model.barCount()
    default:
        return 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you show me your Enum? But:  return FormSection.count should return all possible categories, or? So you create just an enum to identify all your sections, or? Can you show me your numberOfRowsinSection too? Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's the (stripped) enum: https://gist.github.com/whiskey/4def64050c7afdadb6c3

`FormSection.count` returns all sections, correct. I'll add the #rows @ indexPath to my answer.

Comment: Thanks again - i guess i will do the same setup here (i´ve done already "like" still the same, just used not an enum to manage the sections) - so ill just "hide" the not used sections. At the moment it works as expected, i was just not sure if that is a good possibility (to have 20+ sections, but only 2 or 3 are visible)

Comment: I run this usually with less than 10 sections and never had performance issues with this. If you encounter something, please let us know :)

Comment: Thanks - that are good news to me. Ill think thats good solution for that kind of requirements. Greetings to Germany ;)