# How to create a table view with a section?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

My Table View right now is in "dynamic prototypes" so basically i cant add section by just increment the section like static cell. but i like to maintain in dynamic prototype. So how exactly can i create a section that contain their own cell?

Here is my code:

```
class ProfileViewController: BaseViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var profileTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var profileImg: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bigIDLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var userNameLbl: UILabel!

    let titleArr = ["My Profile", "My BIG Point", "Options"]
    var detailArr = [String]()

    let userInfo = defaults.objectForKey("userInfo")
    let userTicketId = defaults.objectForKey("userticketId") as! String

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //setupWhiteLeftButton()
        self.navigationItem.title = "My Profile"

        bigIDLbl.text = "BIG ID : \(userInfo!["CustomerNumber"] as! String)"
        userNameLbl.text = "\((userInfo!["FirstName"] as! String).capitalizedString) \((userInfo!["LastName"] as! String).capitalizedString)"
         detailArr = ["\((userInfo!["FirstName"] as! String).capitalizedString) \((userInfo!["LastName"] as! String).capitalizedString)", "8,950pts", ""]

        let username = userInfo!["UserName"] as! String
        let password = defaults.objectForKey("userPassword") as! String

        AirAsiaBigProvider.request(.GetUser(username, password, userTicketId), completion: { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .Success(let successResult):
                do {

                    let json = try JSON(NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(successResult.data, options: .MutableContainers))

                    if json["Status"].string == "OK" {
                        defaults.setValue(json.object, forKey: "userData")
                    } else if json["Status"].string == "Error" {
                        showErrorMessage(json["Message"].string!)
                    }

                }
                catch {
                    showErrorMessage("Unable to connect the server")
                }
            case .Failure(let failureResult):
                showErrorMessage(failureResult.nsError.localizedDescription)
            }
        })



        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func profileImgPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)


        let choosePhoto = UIAlertAction(title: "Choose From Photos", style: .Default, handler: {
            (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            NSLog("Action 1 Clicked")

            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.PhotoLibrary) {
                let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
                imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
                imagePicker.delegate = self
                imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
                self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                showErrorMessage("Error Launch Photos")
            }
        })

        let takePhoto = UIAlertAction(title: "Take Photo", style: .Default, handler: {
            (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            NSLog("Action 2 Clicked")

            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.Camera) {
                let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
                imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
                imagePicker.delegate = self
                imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
                self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                showErrorMessage("Error Taking Photo")
            }
        })

        let deletePhoto = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete Photo", style: .Default, handler: {
            (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            NSLog("Action 3 Clicked")
            self.profileImg.image = UIImage(named: "profileImg")
        })

        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)

        alert.addAction(choosePhoto)
        alert.addAction(takePhoto)
        alert.addAction(deletePhoto)
        alert.addAction(cancel)
        presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        profileImg.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
        profileImg.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
        profileImg.clipsToBounds = true
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return titleArr.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 40
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = profileTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomProfileTableViewCell
        cell.title.text = titleArr[indexPath.row]
        cell.detail.text = detailArr[indexPath.row]
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        return cell

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


        if indexPath.row == 0 {

            let storyboard2 = UIStoryboard(name: "Profile", bundle: nil)
            let myProfileVC = storyboard2.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewProfileVC") as! myProfileTableViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(myProfileVC, animated: true)
        } else if indexPath.row == 2{

            let storyboard2 = UIStoryboard(name: "Profile", bundle: nil)
            let profileVC = storyboard2.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("OptionsVC") as! OptionsViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(profileVC, animated: true)
        }

    }

    func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
        print("User Login")
    }
    func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {

        print("User Logged Out")
    }

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: Use func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1 //Number of section you want in your tableview
    } Don't forget to add UITableViewDataSource in your viewcontroller.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITableView with different optional sections?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31741035/uitableview-with-different-optional-sections)

Comment: got it. But it duplicate on my first row. And how can i edit the title of the section?

Answer (score 1):

By this way you can add sections in your tableView

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        profileTableView.delegate = self
        profileTableView.dataSource = self
  }


func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2 // As per your requirement you can return no of sections.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String
    {
        if section == 0
        {
            return "Section A"
        }
        else
        {
            return "Section B"
        }
    }
```