# Swift - how to make custom header sections for UITableView using enum?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

Hi guys inside my tableView class i have following enum

```swift
enum tabelSecion { 
    case action 
    case drama 
    case comedy
}
```

i need to use this enum to have 3 different section header. also i created a nib to represents a custom sectionHeaderCell which has only a label inside it.how can i show section headers?
appreciate for your help

Comment: I guess [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31741336/5928311) can help you and read comments also. I mean [this](https://gist.github.com/whiskey/4def64050c7afdadb6c3)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by extending your enum with a dynamic var `SectionTitle`.

```swift
enum TabelSection: Int, CaseIterable { 
    case action 
    case drama 
    case comedy

    var sectionTitle: String {
        switch self {
        case action: return "Action"
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

By making you enum an Int, it is possible to init it with a rawValue. The rawValue to init it is the section it you get from the TableView Method.

The CaseIterable is also quit nice so you can get the number cases (=sections) from it for the `numberOfSections` Method.

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return TabelSection(rawValue: section)?.sectionTitle
}
```

---

**Edit:**
To display a `headerView` for each section of the tableView change the TableViewstyle to `Grouped`

[image]

In your code just provide the tableView with the correct amount of sections.

```swift
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return TabelSection.allCases.count
}
```

If you really need a custom HeaderView you may use the following Method to do so

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help but how should i dequeue customHeaderSectionCell which has only a label inside?

Comment: because the section header cell's label needs to get updated to "Action", "Drama"...

Comment: You do not need a custom cell for this. The headerView already provides a label. Overriding `titleForHeaderInSection` allows you to configure which text will be displayed for each section